# Post conditions and limited in out parameters

Tags: ada, gnat

How to specify limited in out parameter is unmodified during subprogram call by post condition? Consider the following code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   package C is

      type Printer is tagged limited private;

      procedure Print
        (P : in out Printer;
         B : Integer);

   private

      type Printer is tagged limited record
         A : Integer := 0;
      end record;

   end C;

   package body C is

      procedure Print
        (P : in out Printer;
         B : Integer) is
      begin
         if B >= 0 then
            P.A := B;
         end if;
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (P.A'Image);
      end Print;

   end C;

   P : C.Printer;
begin
   P.Print (-1);
end Main;
```

When a negative number is specified as input to the Print subprogram the internal state of Printer instances is unchanged during the subprogram call. What is the best way to specify this? Trying the following yields the error message "attribute 'Old' cannot apply to limited objects":

```
procedure Print
    (P : in out Printer;
     B : Integer) with
    Post => (if B < 0 then P'Old = P);
```

Can the solution perhaps be found in delta aggregates in the Ada 2020 standard?

EDIT: This can be a tricky question considering that limited types does not by definition have any equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RM 6.1.1](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-1-1.html)

> For each X'Old in a postcondition expression that is enabled, a
>   constant is implicitly declared at the beginning of the subprogram or
>   entry. The constant is of the type of X and is initialized to the
>   result of evaluating X (as an expression) at the point of the constant
>   declaration. The value of X'Old in the postcondition expression is the
>   value of this constant; the type of X'Old is the type of X. These
>   implicit constant declarations occur in an arbitrary order.

The AARM is quite explicite:

> 'Old makes no sense for limited types, because its implementation
>   involves copying. It might make semantic sense to allow
>   build-in-place, but it's not worth the trouble.

I don't think delta aggregates would solve the issue because I don't see how it would prevent the implicit copy.

However, while you cannot apply `'old` to a limited object, you can apply it to one or more of its non-limited component.

```
  procedure Print
    (P : in out Printer;
     B : Integer) with Post => (if B < 0 then P.A'Old = P.A);
```

Of course, in your example, component A is private so this would not work and is in general not desirable for public procedures.

To solve this, you may want to wrap the component in a getter function and write:

```
      function Printer_Value (P : in Printer) return Integer;

      procedure Print
        (P : in out Printer;
         B : Integer) with Post => (if B < 0 then P.Printer_Value'Old = P.Printer_Value);

   private

      function Printer_Value (P : in Printer) return Integer is (P.A);
```

and then tune Printer_Value to manually include components that should be checked for invariance. But this would also fails to compile because `P.Printer_Value'Old` is potentially unevaluated (when `B>=0`). AARM states the usual solution is to do `P'Old.Printer_Value` but this is not possible because P is limited. So to make it work, we have to evaluate it unconditionally:

```
  procedure Print
    (P : in out Printer;
     B : Integer) with Post => P.Printer_Value'Old = P.Printer_Value or else B >= 0;
```

This achieve almost what you wanted but I doubt it's worth the trouble because of the maintenance burden.